# How to set the background color of statusbar in android?

Tags: android

Is there hava way to set the background color of statusbar? I want to my actionbar's background color keep the same with the statusbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible with android 5.0+, and you simply need to use the right theme and parameters

Create or modify your themes.xml, and apply the theme to your application in manifest, and of course, you have to define your own color as well.

**values/themes.xml:**

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name=”colorAccent”>@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score -1):

colorPrimaryDark in lollipop represents the statusBar Color

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_theme</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main_theme_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_theme_accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_theme_text_color</item>
</style>
```

You may also use

```
item name="android:statusBarColor"
```

And in java

```
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.argb(40, 0, 0, 0));
```